# How to get files from a directory created between two dates using DateTimePickers

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I want to get files created between two dates from a directory.  The dates are selected by two DateTimePickers.

Example (user selectable):

```
datetimerpicker1 = "15/09/2015";
datetimerpicker2 = "05/10/2015";
```

I put as var

```
        var dataInicio = dataInicial.Value;
        var dataFim = dataFinal.Value;

        string entradaDeDiretorio = @"C:\\";

        DirectoryInfo diretorioDeEntrada = new DirectoryInfo(entradaDeDiretorio);

        if (dataInicio != dataFim)
        {
            foreach (var arquivos in diretorioDeEntrada.GetFiles().Where(f => f.CreationTime >= dataInicio && f.CreationTime <= dataFim))
            {
                // call the function
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var arquivos in diretorioDeEntrada.GetFiles().Where(f => f.CreationTime == dataInicio && f.CreationTime == dataFim))
            {
                // call the function                                        
            }
        }
```

Comment: Excuse! I wrote the wrong example. It is: DateTimePicker1 = "15/09/2015"; datetimerpicker2 = "05/10/2015";

Comment: I fixed the date, you can approve the fix.

Comment: @CezarSystems You can use the "edit" link below your question to edit your question

Comment: Don't forget to add a day to your end date range if you want to include files on that date since plain dates don't have a time component and time-stamps (usually) do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get files from your directory within a range of date try this:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(your_dir);
var files = directory.GetFiles()
    .Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= DateTimePicker1
           && file.LastWriteTime <= datetimerpicker2);
```

EDIT 1:
If both datepicker's value are the same you can simply query for either datepicker's date value and not query against a range

```
 if(dataInicio != dataFim)
  (var arquivos in diretorioDeEntrada.GetFiles().Where(f => f.CreationTime >= dataInicio && f.CreationTime <= dataFim));
 else
   (var arquivos in diretorioDeEntrada.GetFiles().Where(f => f.CreationTime == dataInicio));
```

Comment: was this helpful to you?

Comment: Good Morning! Made according to sample testing up and realized that the where clause does not return the same day files. Example: Start date: 13/06/2016 End date: 13/06/2016. can you help me?

(var arquivos in diretorioDeEntrada.GetFiles().Where(f => f.CreationTime >= dataInicio && f.CreationTime <= dataFim))

Comment: What's the class of dataInicio and dataFim. The comparison inside if expression might change based on their class. I just assumed they are strings

Comment: If the file was modified ON the end date, and you want to include it, don't forget to add a day to the end of the date range..